# How to center my form in the middle of the content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap [example](http://jsbin.com/EKEHeCIX/3) http://jsbin.com/EKEHeCIX/3/edit.
As you can see in the code above my form resides in the top of content. But I need to reside it in the middle.

Is it possible to make this without explicity setting of top in pixels? Because need to get it work for any screens (not tablets or phones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without setting the top pixels.

Use this:

```
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
```

With the position on absolute, you can make this responsive for any screensize.

You might want to take a look at this:
[Absolute Centering](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)

This can help you out with alot of centering/styling issues!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact width and height of your element you could do something like:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -220px;
}
```

Setting `margin-top` as 50% of element's height and `margin-left` as the 50% of element's `width`.
And obviously you must add `class="centered"` to your element.
Here is your example: http://jsbin.com/EKEHeCIX/6

If you don't know the size of the element or it has a *mutable* size, you could (using jQuery) implement the css code with javascript:

```
$(function() {
  var $obj = $('.centered');
  $obj.css({
    marginTop:  -($obj.outerHeight() / 2),
    marginLeft: -($obj.outerWidth() / 2)
  });
});
```

Demo with javascript: http://jsbin.com/EKEHeCIX/7

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick :

```
.form-signin {
    width: 400px;
    height: 230px;
    position: absolute;
    /* top:50px for header size */
    /* bottom:60px for footer size */
    top: 50px; bottom: 60px; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**[JSBin updated](http://jsbin.com/EKEHeCIX/9/edit)**

Comment: Thanks for the response but it seems form is not centered well http://screencast.com/t/z8MVeWB6p4

Comment: @Erik You can ajust this with `top` and `bottom`, I edited my answer to do it.

Comment: Also when I set position: absolute I get the following http://screencast.com/t/F7rI7QrIHOkn the footer overlaps main context instead scroll to be visible

Comment: is it possible to fix?